# How to use qt creator for non qt, non cmake project?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I want to use qt creator for modifying a project that just uses makefiles. How i can do it? Right now i can just open project files one by one and there is no auto code completion or other advantages of ide. My main concern is use the ide over ssh actually.

I tried open all folder but it didnt work too.

Comment: What advantage is there for using Qt Creator on a non-Qt project?

Comment: Can you recommend a free c++ ide over qt creator for linux? its the one of the best i used/found, other was emacs but i couldnt find enough documentation to how to configure it like an ide.(ui, functionalites ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Qt Creator for non-Qt projects, but it will always assume you want to use qmake, CMake, or QBS as your build system. It's not going to read your plain Makefiles and recognize what source files you are using.

In the New Project wizard, you can select non-Qt application. I recommend selecting qmake as your build system, which will create a .pro file, even if you won't end up using it. Then after it creates the project, go into your Project settings under `Build Steps`. You can delete the built-in steps and add your own custom build steps to do whatever you want. Call `make` or whatever. Do the same for the `Clean Steps`.

Comment: In the top of the "Build steps" it says: "Make: make not found in the environment"  .I got "Skipping disabled step Make." in compile output.

Comment: Is make installed? I can't imagine it's not. If you need to add a path to your environment, there's a section called "Build Environment" down below that.

Comment: Yes make installed and works flawlessly in my terminal. I tried that section too but still same.

Comment: Try using the full path to your make executable. i don't know why it wouldn't be able to find it.